# Prove that: $|ρ(x,y)−ρ(x,u)|≤ρ(u,y)$ with $x,y,z \in E$ and $\rho$ is a norm

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Is valid to take the third propriety of metric space and make this?
$$ρ(x,y)≤ρ(x,u)+ρ(u,y)$$
$$ρ(x,y)-ρ(x,u)≤ρ(u,y) \ | ()^2$$
$$|ρ(x,y)-ρ(x,u)| ≤ρ(u,y)$$

Is this well? Sorry for isn't a great question.

Comment: For real numbers $a$ and $r$, the inequality $|a| \leq r$ *is equivalent* to the inequality $-r \leq a \leq r$; so, what you need to prove is also that $-ρ(u,y) \leq ρ(x,y)-ρ(x,u)$ since you already have $ρ(x,y)-ρ(x,u) \leq ρ(u,y)$. Can you do that?

Comment: A norm is a function of one variable, you probably meant $\rho$ is a metric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the problem correctly, you can apply the triangle inequality twice to obtain the desired result. Indeed, one has:
\begin{align*}
\|x\| = \|x + y - y\| \leq \|x + y\| + \|y\| \Rightarrow \|x + y\| \geq \|x\| - \|y\|
\end{align*}

Similarly, we get that
\begin{align*}
\|y\| = \|x + y - x\| \leq \|x + y\| + \|y\| \Rightarrow \|x + y\| \geq \|y\| - \|x\|
\end{align*}

Gathering both results, we get the desired claim:
\begin{align*}
\|x + y\| \geq \max\{\|x\| - \|y\|,\|y\| - \|x\|\} = |\|x\| - \|y\||
\end{align*}
and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: In the last part of this answer, where can watch more for $max{}$? And to take advantage of this, where find more theory about functional analysis?

Comment: The max part is one of the possible definitions for the absolute value.  As to the functional analysis reference, I am afraid I cannot provide it.